# Right click menu and calendar are still white even after enabling the dark mode

Tags: gnome, themes, appearance

I enabled global dark mode from settings which should make everything dark, but still the right click menu and calendar are white. I don't want to install any additional unofficial themes just to achieve this. But instead interested to know why this hasn't been fixed yet because people have been complaining about this since Ubuntu 12.

Some Derivatives of Ubuntu like Pop OS have everything dark on dark theme including the ones that I mentioned. Then why does Ubuntu has it like that?

Comment: Hi Vin, what is the Ubuntu version rite now you are using?

Comment: 20.04 which I think is the latest available version as of now.

Comment: Ok, so you must have installed gnome-tweaks and then changed Appearance to Highcontrast? Can you share a pic how you did that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmu1b.jpg

Comment: I did not install anything extra. I only installed Ubuntu a few days ago and did this `Settings -> Appearance -> Dark` which is supposed to make everything dark, but it didn't. Are you using Ubuntu? It should be same for you too or anyone else using Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, good info.. can you open settings.. and then search for universal access menu and there turn on Highcontrast.. nothing to install anything..

Comment: The way you are using "Dark" via Settings Appearance Dark, is only for the Appearence Theme which will have effect on GTK Theme only.. the calendar and right click menu are part of gnome-shell, thus It will not have any effect.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0huWg.gif

Comment: So, there is no solution for this? Pop OS doesn't have this issue. How can I make gnome-shell dark then? Turing on high contrast makes everything else white.

Comment: yes turning on high contrast makes everything else white you are rite.. the workaround is to choose gnome-shell theme as `Yaru-dark` if you want to use default dark theme from Ubuntu 20.04 but in order to choose `Yaru-dark` you need to install User Theme gnome-shell Extension.

Comment: if you dont want to install User Theme Extension.. your only option will be to edit a system file. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI3pY.gif

Comment: I'm interested in editing the system file  option if that doesn't affect the performance negatively in any way.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to install GNOME Tweaks via:

```
apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

and starting it to configure the appearance.

The setting *Appearance* → *Shell* was set to *Default* and setting it to *Yaru-dark* did the trick. The Yaru-dark theme was installed manually by me before, but I don't think it's necessary when you already have a theme installed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Based on this I fixed mine in 22.04, but I chose dark theme in normal system settings and "default" in tweaks for the shell theme